# Getting NullPointerException while using NFC Tag

Tags: android, android-fragments, nfc

I am creating a android app using NFC card Reader.I'm getting an issue while using the NFC Tag in Fragment, It's giving a **Nullpointer exception**

```
    AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.root.officeapp, PID: 10347
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
    'boolean android.nfc.Tag.hasTech(int)' on a null object reference
```

i use the bellow code in fragment

```
 @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
          Tag  tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
       }
```

What Should i do now any suggestion will be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used NFC before. I created a transparent activity and set it default like this.

```
<activity ....>
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
     </intent-filter>

     <meta-data
         android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
         android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
</activity>
```

When I read an nfc card,this activity triggered. I read the card content and I passed data from this activity to another activity. Also, I show a progress dialog during reading card and process it.

There is an example code in  [this site](https://www.codexpedia.com/android/android-nfc-read-and-write-example/)

Also you have to sure the nfc card is not empty.